# Por que no me funciona el XML tras cambiar la version compileSdk

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, build.gradle

He cambiado el `compileSdk` y la `targetSdk` de 32 a 33, ya que me estaba dando problemas de **aar metadata**, tras eso ahora cada vez que intento añadir una propiedad en el xml no me deja y me salta error o no me los aplica.

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.examen2evaluacion"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

En este caso el **Edit Text** no se mueve en lo absoluto.
**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:gravity="center">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNombre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Introduce tu nombre"
        style="@style/letraNaranja"
        android:layout_margin_left="50mm"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Y al darle **ctrl + spacio** no me muestra las sugerencias para completar el código como antes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que tu configuración fue cambiada, revisa si la sugerencia automática esta activada, desde el menú ingresa a:

`File` > `Settings` > `Editor` > `General` > `Code Completion`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto no tiene que ver con cambiar el `compileSdk` y la `targetSdk` de tu proyecto.

Comment: Lo acabo de ver y si esta marcado. Cambie el compileSdk a 32 y el targetSdk lo deje en 33 y ahí si se me completa los XML pero me salen errores al ejecutar.